# Call to a member function getValue() on null in ./Model/Method/AbstractMethod.php:801 for Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Hi i have creating payment method but i was stuck here

Getting Fatal error in checkout page:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getValue() on null in /home/vhost/_default/magentoto/vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/Method/AbstractMethod.php:801
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vhost/_default/magentoto/generated/code/Mymodule/Iveri/Model/PaymentMethod/Interceptor.php(596): Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod-&gt;getConfigData('sort_order', '1')
#1 /home/vhost/_default/magentoto/vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/PaymentMethodList.php(58): Mymodule\Iveri\Model\PaymentMethod\Interceptor-&gt;getConfigData('sort_order', '1')
#2 [internal function]: Magento\Payment\Model\PaymentMethodList-&gt;Magento\Payment\Model\{closure}(Object(Mymodule\Iveri\Model\PaymentMethod\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Vault\Model\Method\Vault\Interceptor))
#3 /home/vhost/_default/magentoto/vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/PaymentMethodList.php(59): uasort(Array, Object(Closure))
#4 /home/vhost/_default/magentoto/vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/PaymentMethodList.php(84): Magento\Payment\Model\PaymentMethodList-&gt;getList('1')
#5 /home/vh in <b>/home/vhost/_default/magentoto/vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/Method/AbstractMethod.php</b> on line <b>801</b><br />
```

Also i have searched about this issue but not getting any solution also file is path is different for this type of questions.

If anyone know about this bug. please provide solution (Thanks in Advance)

Comment: Please specify your Magento version and add your code in the question.

Comment: I have used Magento ver. 2.2.3